# Hair final render nothing like viewport render

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

The hair is controlled via a curve nested within a collection due to the limitations of Blenders hair system. The curves top point was then twisted to get the twisted look.

The viewport render is exactly what I want, when rendering I get completely different results.

Setting

[image: Hair Setting]
[image: Hair Setting]

[image: Blender Cycles Viewport Preview]

[image: Blender Cycles Render]

Comment: hard to guess without any additional info like hair settings or whole file with that strand, did you allow all settings to be visible in render? Are you using children in your hair settings?

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Check the *Viewport Display* and *Render* section for a *Steps* value